# item value when emitting the update event is null

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, arrow-functions

```
onCardClicked(item: BudgetItem) {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditItemModalComponent, {
  width: '580px',
  data: item
})

console.log(item)

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  // check if result has a value
  if (result) {
    console.log(item)

    this.update.emit(
      {
        old: item,
        new: result
      }
    );
  }

})}
```

When I try to read the value of item inside of subscribe() , it appears to be null. As per my knowledge as arrow function should be able to use the value from the local scope.. hence item value should be read.

Hence as a result , angular cannot calculate the total budget and shows incorrect total in the main page component.

If anyone has any idea, please help!

Please find the full code in stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tvrqgd?file=src/app/budget-item-list/budget-item-list.component.ts

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz where it can be reproduced?

Comment: HI Akash, Please refer the budget-item-list component ts file.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uybudk?file=src/app/budget-item-list/budget-item-list.component.ts

Comment: There is no such file in this stackblitz. only readme and package.json is there.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/KapilBillore/Budget-App/tree/master

Comment: Pardon for it. I am actually first time using stackblitz. Code is visvible now to the link but it shows some wierd error at compilation that it cannot find the model , Budget-item.ts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will have data in result parameter you are receiving in subscribe callback. Arrow function don't have local scope. If you still want to use items instead of result you have to convert it into non arrow function and bind it like below :-

```
 onCardClicked(item: BudgetItem) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditItemModalComponent, {
      width: '580px',
      data: item,
    });

    console.log(item);
    var closeCallback = function (result) {
      // check if result has a value
      console.log('result');
      console.log(result);
      if (result) {
        console.log(item);

        this.update.emit({
          old: item,
          new: result,
        });
      }
    }.bind(this);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(closeCallback);
  }
```

Working Stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tvrqgd?file=src/app/budget-item-list/budget-item-list.component.ts

Comment: I tried the same. In the stackblitz i still find the value of item inside the if statment as null..

Comment: see it on my stackblitz

Comment: Hi Akash, i hve checked the console.log(item) inside of if loop is still giving null..YOu can also check the same, when you add an item lets say {meds, 50} and update it to {med, 500} then as per the code , when the event update emits, it goes to main page component and update the total at the top.. so in ideal case it should be 500, but since we are passing old in the event, which has value of item which inturn is null.. hence it totals to 550 and doesnt minus the value.